# How to refresh listview in Fragment from another activity after finish()?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, socket.io, android-adapter

I use FragmentPagerAdapter in my android project. I use too socket.io and I need to refresh a listview in fragment after received data by socket.

**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

@StringRes
private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2};
private final Context mContext;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Collections collections = new Collections();
            return collections;

        case 1:
            List list = new List();
            return list;

        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 2 total pages.
    return TAB_TITLES.length;
}
}
```

Below is my fragment code:

**ListView Fragment**

```
public class List extends Fragment {

JSONArray LIST_DATA = new JSONArray();

ListViewAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);

    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    FloatingActionButton addSong = view.findViewById(R.id.addButton);

    GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter();
    JSONObject jsonObject = getterSetter.getJsonObject();

    try {
        LIST_DATA = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), LIST_DATA);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    addSong.setOnClickListener(new FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddSong.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

and my socket.io

**SocketIo receiver**

```
private Ack createSong = new Ack() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JSONArray GRID_DATA = new JSONArray();

                try {
                    GRID_DATA = new JSONArray(""+args[1]);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter();
                getterSetter.setJsonArray(GRID_DATA);
                Log.d("name", String.valueOf(GRID_DATA));

                finish();

            }
        });
    }
};
```

How can I refresh my listview adapter after called finish() method?